# How to display specific images in PHP through MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display each specific image to display in PHP/HTML page, it's currently displaying all the pages but I would like it to only display one for whenever I type in the function.

My code:

```
 <div class="ser-grid-list img_style">
                            <div class="gallery1">


                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ser-grid-list img_style">
                            <div class="gallery1">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ser-grid-list img_style">
                            <div class="gallery1">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ser-grid-list img_style">
                            <div class="gallery1">
                                                            <?php
 $sql = "SELECT image FROM product"; //sql query
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($connection));
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //display the results
 {
 echo "<p><img src='../images/" . ($row['image']) . "'" . " " . " />"; 
 }

?>
```

What its doing:

http://puu.sh/cCs29/6769667d43.jpg

What I'm wanting to make them do is align from left to right. It was working with Static images coming through html but I decided to use a database. This was it prior

http://puu.sh/cCs5g/919c0c8c57.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: Please care about the fact that mysql_* functions are deprecated. You should use PDO instead, there are many tutorials to learn how to use this. If your PHP version is recent enough and errors are on and E_ALL, your script will generate a E_DEPRECATED error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply get the id of your image just like this one

```
 $sql = "SELECT image FROM product where id=101";
```

This is the easiest one? Am i missing something?

Comment: CodeSlayer, you're a life saver! :)

Answer (score 2):

`<p>` is a block element, so it'll start and end with a new line. If you want to display them inline, try eliminating the `<p>` tags surrounding the `<img>` tags.

And as @CodeSlayer suggests, if you only want one single image returned, add a `WHERE` clause to your query to fetch a specific image.